# Error: could not find function "setup_twitter_oauth

Tags: api, twitter, oauth

When I run my API setup code on my laptop I don't have a problem, but when my friend runs it she is getting this message.

Error:

> could not find function "setup_twitter_oauth"

The code is *(I took out all the personal info obv)*:

```
options(RCurlOptions = list( capath = system.file
("CurlSSL", "cacert.pem", package = "RCurl"), ssl.verifypeer = FALSE)) 
reqURL<-"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/request_token" accessURL<-
"https://api.twitter.com/oauth/access_token" authURL<-"//api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize"
```

There's a https: after the "authURL <-" but i don't have 10 reputation to post 3 links:

```
consumerKey<-"XXXX" consumerSecret<-"XXXX" access_token<- "XXXX" access_secret<- "XXXX"

setup_twitter_oauth(consumerKey, consumerSecret, access_token, access_secret)
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Please improve formatting by using  making some parts of question as code, it can be edited)) What language do u use? As I see it should be R, I think problem is related with autif. file, once you autent. it remembers you, but not your friend.

Comment: http://thinktostart.com/twitter-authentification-with-r/ look here, should help

Answer (score 0):

try to use this:

twitteR:::setup_twitter_oauth()

And be sure that you have already install properly the twitter library.